# Loop within a loop for checking whois responses

Tags: c#, windows, uri, httprequest

trying to think of some logic of how to code this.

I'm basically creating a c# windows app to check if a domain is available for registration - by posting and retrieving data from whoIS records.

i have a text file with domain extensions in and the user types in "DOMAINNAME"

then the program will cycle through all of the domain extensions in the file and will report back which ones are available.

This in theory is working fine but im currently implementing proxy support. the proxies are also being stored in a text file.

i basically have the domain extensions in a foreach loop

```
foreach(domainExtension in domainFile)

{
checkDomainAvailability()
}
```

what i need is for the checkDomainAbility method to use a different proxy for each request. 
Any ideas on logic behind coding this?

Answer (score 0):

You could put all of the proxies in a List and keep a class level variable `int lastUsedProxy`.  Then the checkDomainAvailability function just uses those two variables to get the *next in line* proxy and increment the integer. Once lastUsedProxy > List.Count then reset it to zero.  Using this logic you can put more proxies into the list than you have domain extentions (i.e. you can have 30 proxies and only 10 extensions, the proxies will only be used once every three queries).  I think this is similar to what you want. I think one of your purposes is to spread the load between proxies as much as possible and this logic would allow you to do that easily.